# Setup a dynamic var for input Map markers

Tags: javascript, json, markers

I have the following function:

```
$(".mijn_veld").change(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://url.com/index.php?action=pslist&zip='+$(".mijn_veld").val()+'&country=NL', function(result){
        $.each(result.data, function(i, field){
            $(".listings").append(this.name + "<br> ");
        });
    });
});
```

This works perfectly. What I want with this function is to add markers on my Google Map. Let say with this function I get the following JSON reponse:

```
{"status":0,"data":[{"spid":"NL-351202","name":"In 't vosje","add":"Nobelstraat 141","zip":"3512EM","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1246600000","lat":"52.0929748000"},{"spid":"NL-358102","name":"Vivant Verheijen","add":"Burg Reigerstraat 54","zip":"3581KV","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1358400000","lat":"52.0895721000"},{"spid":"NL-351175","name":"Parcelstation deBuren H.Catharijne","add":"Catharijnesingel 11-PS","zip":"3511GB","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1115500000","lat":"52.0922582000"},{"spid":"NL-351403","name":"Vivant De Molen","add":"Adelaarstraat 32","zip":"3514CG","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1158800000","lat":"52.0993884000"},{"spid":"NL-358303","name":"Qualitours","add":"Adr. Van Ostadelaan 41","zip":"3583AA","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1396700000","lat":"52.0832667000"},{"spid":"NL-353103","name":"Ina Ugas 2","add":"Damstraat 64","zip":"3531BW","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1032100000","lat":"52.0922908000"},{"spid":"NL-352203","name":"Cigars N More Utrecht","add":"Rijnlaan 12","zip":"3522BN","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1145300000","lat":"52.0769769000"},{"spid":"NL-357101","name":"Foto Ben Romp","add":"Troosterhof 1","zip":"3571NC","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1356800000","lat":"52.1064315000"},{"spid":"NL-353203","name":"Buurtwinkel Nieuw England","add":"Vleutenseweg 355","zip":"3532HH","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.0961200000","lat":"52.0937046000"},{"spid":"NL-355102","name":"Vivant De Plantage","add":"Amsterdamsestraatweg 279","zip":"3551CE","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.0989600000","lat":"52.1015290000"},{"spid":"NL-352301","name":"Boek en Kantoor Robman","add":"Smaragdplein 224","zip":"3523EH","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1248600000","lat":"52.0721031000"},{"spid":"NL-356202","name":"The Cartridgers Overvecht","add":"Zamenhofdreef 43","zip":"3562JT","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1120700000","lat":"52.1144018000"},{"spid":"NL-355301","name":"Drogisterij de Kamil","add":"Amsterdamsestraatweg 524","zip":"3553EN","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.0844700000","lat":"52.1094875000"},{"spid":"NL-352875","name":"Parcelstation deBuren Utrecht","add":"Papendorpseweg 95-PS","zip":"3528BJ","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.0881500000","lat":"52.0629634000"},{"spid":"NL-354203","name":"DHL Parcel Hoofdkantoor","add":"Reactorweg 25","zip":"3542AD","city":"Utrecht","country":"NL","lon":"5.0640800000","lat":"52.1049812000"},{"spid":"NL-354251","name":"DHL Parcelstation Lage weide","add":"Reactorweg 25-PS","zip":"3542AD","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.0640800000","lat":"52.1049812000"},{"spid":"NL-354244","name":"Test shop","add":"Reactorweg 25","zip":"3542AD","city":"Utrecht","country":"NL","lon":"5.0640800000","lat":"52.1049812000"},{"spid":"NL-373104","name":"CIGO De Bilt","add":"Hessenweg 162","zip":"3731JN","city":"DE BILT","country":"NL","lon":"5.1817900000","lat":"52.1103054000"},{"spid":"NL-354301","name":"G&W Gezondheidswinkel De Weegschaal","add":"Ella Fitzgeraldplein 34","zip":"3543EP","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.0463800000","lat":"52.1015022000"},{"spid":"NL-354202","name":"DHL Parcel Utrecht","add":"Rutherfordweg 1","zip":"3542CN","city":"UTRECHT","country":"NL","lon":"5.0561100000","lat":"52.1204578000"}]}
```

What I now want is to put this data into a VAR so my script will make *markers* at my Map. A example is: (But note: I don't want it static like it is now, each time there will be filled in another zipcode with getJSON, it has to update this VAR.)

```
var stores = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [5.140439, 51.686608]
            },
            "properties": {
                "spid": "NL3700-03",
                "name": "Test Parcel 1",
                "add": "Teststreet 1",
                "zip": "3500RR",
                "city": "utrecht",
                "country": "NL",
                "phone": "032434234",
                "oh": "Ma: 12:00 tot 15:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [5.133729,51.681425]
            },
            "properties": {
                "phoneFormatted": "(202) 507-8357",
                "phone": "2025078357",
                "add": "2221 I St NW",
                "city": "Washington DC",
                "country": "United States",
                "crossStreet": "at 22nd St NW",
                "postalCode": "20037",
                "state": "D.C."
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

**My question:** How can I make this happen? I want to make sure *name* value from the JSON output will be in "name" from the VAR STORES. And this for each store there is.

Answer (score 0):

You can load your JSON into an object called `places` using your first function

```
var places = {};

$(".mijn_veld").change(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://url.com/index.php?action=pslist&zip='+$(".mijn_veld").val()+'&country=NL', function(result) {
        places = result;
    });
});
```

Then just loop through the results, adding them to your own data structure as you go.  In the example, I set places manually, but for your purposes you can load it from that server.

```
var places = {  
   "status":0,
   "data":[  
      {  
         "spid":"NL-351202",
         "name":"In 't vosje",
         "add":"Nobelstraat 141",
         "zip":"3512EM",
         "city":"UTRECHT",
         "country":"NL",
         "lon":"5.1246600000",
         "lat":"52.0929748000"
      },
      {  
         "spid":"NL-358102",
         "name":"Vivant Verheijen",
         "add":"Burg Reigerstraat 54",
         "zip":"3581KV",
         "city":"UTRECHT",
         "country":"NL",
         "lon":"5.1358400000",
         "lat":"52.0895721000"
      },
      {  
         "spid":"NL-351175",
         "name":"Parcelstation deBuren H.Catharijne",
         "add":"Catharijnesingel 11-PS",
         "zip":"3511GB",
         "city":"UTRECHT",
         "country":"NL",
         "lon":"5.1115500000",
         "lat":"52.0922582000"
      }
   ]
};

var stores = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": []
};

for (var i = 0; i < places.data.length; i++) {
    var place = places.data[i];

    stores.features.push({
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [place.lat, place.lon]
         },
         properties: {
        "spid": place.spid,
        "name": place.name,
            "add": place.add,
            "zip": place.zip,
            "city": place.city,
            "country": place.country,
         }
    });
}

console.log(stores);
```

Comment: I get the following error: TypeError: places.data is undefined

Comment: As I said, places.data is undefined. I checked what console tells me, It does see the Object and arrays: Object { status: 0, data: Array[20] }

Comment: I have been tested further. I did delete the var places which you did set manually. Then I get the error which I told earlier.

Comment: add `console.log(places)` before the error occurs and after you load it. what does it contain?

Comment: Object {}
TypeError: places.data is undefined

Which contains: "for (var i = 0; i < places.data.length; i++) {"

Comment: It looks like the var _places_ is not set correctly with the getJSON function.

Comment: Try this `for(var key in places) { console.log(key + " " + places[key]); }` that will show you what kind of keys the object has.  Could provide a clue.  Put that before where the error occurs.

Comment: Hi, the only thing I can see from now is that it does not let me see the input of places.data in this part: $(".mijn_veld").change(function() {
    $.get('http://api.nl/dhl-parcelshop-locator/index.php?action=pslist&zip=5151BT&country=NL', function(result) {
        places = result;
  console.log(places.data);
    });
}); ___ It give me back: TypeError: places.data is undefined

Comment: I used the code, it give me hundred of lines back. Where should I place or replace the code `for(var key in places) { console.log(key + " " + places[key]); }`?

Comment: The problem in my opinion is that the change(function) does store information in var _places_, but I can't use it outside the function. Like: `var places = {};` then `$(".mijn_veld").change(function() {
    $.getJSON('https://api.sendparcel.nl/dhl-parcelshop-locator/index.php?action=pslist&zip='+$(".mijn_veld").val()+'&country=NL', function(result) {
        places = result;
    });
});` and then `console.log(places)` gives me output: `Object {  }. TypeError: places.data is undefined`. With the loop, it can't find the var.

Comment: The first code snippet in my answer declares `places` in global scope.  It will be accessible by the callback of the getJSON request because it has global scope.  Can you just browse to this URL is an internet browser and see the raw JSON that gets returned?